# Mock singleton class with void method using PowerMockito

Tags: java, singleton, mockito, junit4, powermock

I keep on getting WanterButNotInvoked exception on my UT with the below code:

```
@RunWith( PowerMockRunner.class )
@PrepareForTest( { CounterHandler.class, 
TrHandlerProtocolsCounterHandler.class, IProtocolCounterHandler.class } )

@Test
public void testInitialize() 
{
    IProtocolCounterHandler counter = new TrHandlerProtocolsCounterHandler();
    CounterHandler mockCounter = PowerMockito.spy( CounterHandler.getInstance() );
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when( mockCounter ).initialize();

    counter.initialize();
    Mockito.verify( mockCounter ).initialize();
```

}
======================
CounterHandler class

```
public void initialize() {
    //do something
}
```

======================
TrHandlerProtocolsCounterHandler class

```
@Override
public void initialize()  {
    CounterHandler.getInstance().initialize();
}
```

I have debugged that Counterhandler.getInstance.initialize was executed but when im trying to verify it, it says that there were no interactions with the mock. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that you have created a new instance of `CounterHandler` that is the spy of the singleton instance. However, you have done nothing to replace the singleton instance help by the `CounterHandler` class with this spy. Therefore when your class calls `getInstance` it gets the actual instance, not the spy.

What you need to do is mock the constructor call so that the singleton instance is a mock. Read this article which shows how to do it and provides a discussion of alternatives to using Singleton.

[Mocking a singleton with EasyMock and PowerMock](http://redchilliplus.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/unit-testing-in-java-with-easymock-and-powermock/)

Comment: +1 Better to place the content of the article here which is easy to refer. Because the link may get broken after sometime.